# How to display link to another document(image/pdf/doc/xls) in a PDF using Apache FOP?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am having an issue in displaying hyperlink for a Document(image/.pdf/.doc/.xls) inside a PDF. When the user click on the hyperlink,that corresponding Document(image/.pdf/.doc/.xls) has to be displayed in new window.

**Books.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <Book xmlns="http://book.com/one/1.2/" xmlns:ns2="http://test2.com/one/1.2/" xmlns:ns3="http://test3.com/one/1.2/" >
          <Title>Java</Title>
          <ISBN>123</ISBN>
          <Author>Test</Author>
          <BookDocument>
            <ns2:DocumentName>images1.jpeg</ns2:DocumentName>
            <ns2:DocumentContent>/aN2r9pT8HwKXpmvvmt2ifpz5xvmt2ifpz5xukZHBb9Wn4FL0xwW/VpD=</ns2:DocumentContent>
          </BookDocument>
          <BookDocument>
            <ns2:DocumentName>images2.jpeg</ns2:DocumentName>
            <ns2:DocumentContent>/aN2r9pT8HwKXpmvvmt2ifpz5xvmt2ifpz5xukZHBb9Wn4FL0x/VpD=</ns2:DocumentContent>
          </BookDocument>
        </Book>
```

**Books.xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'Book']">

    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="ex"
                page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm"
                margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
                <fo:region-body />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="ex">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                <fo:block space-after="15mm">

                </fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="5mm">
                    Book Details
                </fo:block>

                <fo:block font-size="10pt">
                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                        border-collapse="collapse" border="solid 1px black">

                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" padding="1mm">
                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title :</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border="solid 1px black">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'Title']" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>

                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" padding="1mm">
                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">ISBN :
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border="solid 1px black">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'ISBN']" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>

                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" padding="1mm">
                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">Author :</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border="solid 1px black">
                                    <fo:block>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'Author']" />  
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>

                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" padding="1mm">
                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">Image Names :</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border="solid 1px black">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name() = 'BookDocument']">
                                        <xsl:value-of  select="*[local-name() = 'DocumentName']"/>
                                        <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>


                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

The data inside `<ns2:DocumentContent>` is in base64 encoding format. I need to display the document in new window using the content of `<ns2:DocumentContent>`. Please help me in this.

**This is reply to Kevin comment on 19/06/2013**

Hi Kevin i am new this xslt and xsl-fo, as you told, I have tried to give hyperlink using `<fo:basic-link>` , but link is not opened to show the attached file. below is code which i  am trying

```
<fo:basic-link padding-left="65mm" show-destination="new" text-decoration="underline">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
                                                           <xsl:text>url('data:</xsl:text>
                                                           <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'FileType']" />                
                                                           <xsl:text>;base64,</xsl:text>
                                                           <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'FileAttachment']" />
                                                           <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <fo:inline font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" color="#0000ff" text-decoration="underline"><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'FileName']"/></fo:inline>
                                                    </fo:basic-link>
```

could u please help in this.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to include the actual content inside the PDF (essentially using the PDF as a container), it is possible to do only if your choice of XSL FO renderer supports PDF attachments. Since you state things like Excel and such, I assume this is what you mean.

If your choice of XSL FO engine supports PDF File Attachments in the rendering process, then you would need to write the content of the base64 encoded document stream into a PDF attachment FO construct. You would pass the full encoded document into the "src" attribute for the file attachment in the documented extension. Using RenderX XEP, you can see the documentation for the FO to do this here:

[Support of PDF Annotation and File Attachments](http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#PDF%20Note%20Annotations)

You would use a template similar to this below (note "attachmentContentType" in this example would contain the mimetype for the content you are including you would need to add that into your input XML):

```
<xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:text>url('data:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="attachmentContentType"/>                
            <xsl:text>;base64,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="encodedImageBytes"/>
            <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```

To build out the "src" attribute with something like (using the "data:" scheme to store the whole document in the src attribute.) This would be the "src" attribute to the file-attachment extension. This would embed the file into the PDF as an attachment that can be opened in it's native editor through a PDF viewer that supports this.

src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,/aN2r9pT8HwKXpmvvmt2ifpz5xvmt2ifpz5xukZHBb9Wn4FL0xwW...'"

Comment: Thanks Kevin Brown for your help. I am using the above code snippet inside <fo:external-graphic>, it is working fine in displaying image inside pdf.But in need to show only image links and not image itself in pdf. please help in this if there is any way for this.

Comment: The question is image link to "where". Are you planning to put the image on the web somewhere in a known and accessible location? You cannot just think that putting a link to something will work on the file system. If you want a link to an image inside the PDF (or any other file for that matter) then use fo:basic-link with the URL in the external-destination attribute.

Comment: You also have Base64 encoded bytes of the image. The only way you can include the Image or other type of file to open in a separate window is the way I specified above. You inject the file inside the PDF as a file attachment and you can put on a standard PDF marking (like a paper-clip or pushpin) image into the PDF to launch the file in an external application. This is why you also need the mimetype because this tells what file-association to use to launch the appropriate external application.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have tried the way as u told, but there is an issue. I have pasted the problem description in my question post. could u please help in that. please see in the question.

Comment: @RaoPotla, you are misunderstanding how PDF works. You cannot put a link into a PDF pointing at a bunch of bytes. There are only two ways for you to have a link inside a PDF that when clicked, can open another file. Option (1) is to store that file in a publicly accessible place ... as in http: //mywebsite/myfile.jpg. Then you put that accessible address inside the PDF using basic-link. Option (2) is to store the file inside the PDF. For this, you must use a file-attachment and a XSL FO engine that supports file -attachments. You are trying to do Option (2) using Option (1) markup.

Comment: so you are saying that Apache FOP does not support File Attachments of type(Option 2) with hyperlink, is it?

Comment: PDF file attachments are not in xsl fo standard (obviously as they are specific to PDF). FOP may support them through an extension as does RenderX. Check the documentation.